Non-orientable time
Consider the following toy classical physical theory.
Let the theory take place on a fiber bundle $(E, M, \pi, F)$ such that $M$ is a one dimensional manifold interpreted as time. Define an action $S[A_1, A_2, ...]$ over the bundle in terms of dynamic variables.
Seemingly, having $M$ be an orientable manifold (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$) is an arbitrary choice (biased by human experience).
There exist non-orientable non-Hausdorff one dimensional manifolds. What are, if any, the reasons not coming from an appeal to convenience to not take $M$ to be a non-orientable manifold? And, if we do take $M$ to be non-orientable, what sort of physical repercussions do we get?

"There exist non-orientable one dimensional manifolds" if one drops the Hausdorff condition (according to the link you provided). I think this should be clear in the question, so I'm mentioning it explicitly here

@NíckolasAlves thanks, I've edited the question to include this clarification

"Seemingly, having M
be an orientable manifold (e.g. R
) is an arbitrary choice" I know this question is theoretical physics but let's remember that the "axioms" of physics are observations of nature. Otherwise this is a maths exercise, no?


Non-orientable 1d manifolds are non-Hausdorff, as Níckolas Alves
 also says in a comment to the question. Before we even get to loss of time-orientability, loss of Hausdorffness is pretty troubling in general because it destroys a lot of other properties we take for granted (such as uniqueness of solutions to the PDEs generated by a vector flow). See this answer by Slereah for a longer discussion of why spacetime should be Hausdorff.

In higher spacetime dimensions, where non-time-orientability does not imply non-Hausdorffness, it is a bit more feasible to consider its absence. However, to describe the real world, which almost certainly has fermions in it, we need time-orientability since Lorentzian spin structures require time-orientability and vanishing second Stiefel-Whitney class, see also this answer of mine.



For the second point, you mentioned it in your linked answer, but for directness, I think it’s worth being explicit here as well and add in orientability in the statement: “… Lorentzian spin structures require orientability, time-orientability and vanishing second Stiefel-Whitney class”
